# Resource Not Found 404 Error when making an API call from cURL

Tags: api, http, curl, request, httpresponse

I'm doing a CTF activity that I have been working on for the past week and I cannot seem to figure out what is going wrong. To break it down it goes something like this:

- It is an application that consist of 3 tabs, "Balances", "Transactions", and "Payments"
- Everytime you click on one of those tabs, information is displayed which comes from an API.
- But the API call for "Balances" is broken, when it is requested, nothing shows up under the Balance tab and it returns a 404 resource not found error.

So far I've used cURL to try and talk to the API through that and made sure there was no errors in the spelling of the requested site but still no luck.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction or maybe suggest an approach to take instead of giving out what to do step for step which would be much appreciated :).

Edit: The API call is intentionally broken, the challenge is to figure out why it is broken and how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: If it worked sometime in the past, maybe something has changed in the API. If it never worked, maybe is just a spelling mistake or similar in your API call... I know you has said you reviewed it, do it again.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an issue on the resource's end? Are you making calls locally or via a browser?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I am making the through this site to run the cURL commands -https://reqbin.com/curl

Comment: If you're absolutely sure you're querying the right url, then it must be an issue on the service end. But to be sure I'd replicate the call using postman to see if I can reproduce the issue. Postman queries apis directly, circumventing browsers and effectively removing the middleman. So if you get the same issue on Postman, you know it's got nothing to do with the way a browser is handling the call either. With this information, you should open a technical support ticket with the authors of the api and try to get the issue resolved via official support channels.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thank you for this approach, I'll test it out and see the result.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError unfortunately running it through Postman gives the same HTTP response as if I were to run a cURL command. I think it is because since the API is intentionally broken, I have to find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kek just solved this very challenge.

Have you considered that the "Cyber Gang" (context of the challenge) may have changed the endpoint from balances to something else?

Considering that you get a 404 balance from curling get-balances, perhaps you could figure out a way to find other subdomains :)

Comment: The way you worded it is exactly how I was looking for. I was able to capture the flag.